# What makes this while loop an infinite while loop until I use the break command in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to understand what's wrong with the following code.

This version, using boolean values, works fine with or without the `break`:

```
print("Enter your names for the contest exactly the way you want it spelled.")
list_done = False
while list_done == False:
    name = input("Enter your first name: ")
    others_there = input("Are there other participants? Type Y or N: ").lower()
    if others_there == "y":
        list_done == False
        print("Call the next participant!")
    elif others_there == "n":
        list_done = True
        print("We're done. We'll contact you soon.")
        break
```

However, when I try using integer values for `list_done`, the `break` is required to exit the loop, or else it runs indefinitely. Why is that?

```
print("Enter your names for the contest exactly the way you want it spelled.")
list_done = 0
while list_done == 0:
    name = input("Enter your first name: ")
    others_there = input("Are there other participants? Type Y or N: ").lower()
    if others_there == "y":
        list_done == 0
        print("Call the next participant!")
    elif others_there == "n":
        list_done == 1
        print("We're done. We'll contact you soon.")
        #break
```

Comment: I thought even without the break it will stop, assuming you eventually enter ‘n’. Should also be list_done=false in the if statement I think

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I can't reproduce the issue. When I remove `break` then run the script and put `n` at the `Are there other participants` prompt, it exits. Please make a [mre]. You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: BTW, why is `list_done == False` there? You might have meant `list_done = False`, but `list_done` is already `False`.

Comment: It works the same if you remove the `break`; so your question is incorrect. Please fix your question.

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak Thanks for pointing that out. When I was trying different ways using while and while not, I think I got it wrong, but shouldn't the same logic work for numerical values as well?

Comment: @wjandrea yes, I meant list_done = False, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. As such, please do not talk about your level of experience, nor edit questions to mark them as "solved". If you are satisfied that the problem was just a typo, you may delete the question - the main reason questions are left around here is so that they can help someone else in the future. Many of the best questions on the site have received new answers literally years after they were asked. Our primary interest is in *the question itself*.

Comment: Note that you wrote: `list_done == 0` and `list_done == 1` instead of `list_done = 0` and `list_done = 1`, so the value of `list_done` will not be changed, and thus the loop will not stop.

Answer (score 1):

You confused assignment and comparison. Instruction `list_done = False` assigns the `False` value to `list_done`. When you use `list_done == False` you just calculate if `list_done` is equal to `False`.

So the mistake is about lines with `list_done == False`, `list_done == True`, `list_done == 0`. If you fix `==` with `=`, everything will work as you desire.

Comment: Got it now, thanks!

Comment: @PythonistGal welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer helped you consider marking it as right.